# How to avoid page refresh if data is not fill up in php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page in which there are two form inside these forms each have one input , each have a button with different name submit1 and submit2 , I want to submit the data if I select content 1 using javascript and If I select content2 link then the form2 shows and When I click on submit1 then the error2 is showing but when I click on submit2 then the error2 is showing but content changes to content1 , here is my code hope you understand that

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
  if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    echo "please fill form 1 data";
  }
}
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
  if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    echo "please fill form 2 data";

  }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function show(shown, hidden) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="Page1">
    Content of page 1
    <a href="test7.php" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');">Show page 2</a>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <button type="submit" name="submit1">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    Content of page 2
    <a href="test8.php" onclick="return show('Page1','Page2');">Show page 1</a>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <button type="submit" name="submit2">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could do something along the lines of  `return data.length ? DataPage : Loading Page`

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is an option, here is a simple way using .toggle()

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
  if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    echo "please fill form 1 data";
  }
}
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
  if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    echo "please fill form 2 data";
  }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function(){ //this waits for the dom to be loaded before running
  $(".toggle").click(function(){
    $(".toggable-div").toggle();
  })

})
function show(shown, hidden) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Page1" class="toggable-div">
  <h1>Content of page 1</h1>
  <!--the href should be empty, because you don't want the link to go anywhere-->
  <a href="#" class="toggle">Show page 2</a>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button type="submit" name="submit1">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="Page2" style="display:none" class="toggable-div">
  <h1>Content of page 2</h1>
  <!--the href should be empty, because you don't want the link to go anywhere-->
  <a href="#" class="toggle">Show page 1</a>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button type="submit" name="submit2">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```